# Find $\inf _{a,b,c\in \mathbb C}\int _{[-\pi,\pi]}|x+a+b\cos x+c\sin x | ^2dx$

Tags: functional-analysis, definite-integrals, inner-products, orthogonality

I need to find $\inf _{a,b,c\in \mathbb C}\int _{[-\pi,\pi]}|x+a+b\cos x+c\sin x | ^2dx$. I thought about using the fact $\int _{[-\pi,\pi]}f\bar g$ is an inner product $ \left\langle f,g \right\rangle $ for which $1,\cos x,\sin x$ are orthogonal. Then I need to calculate $\inf_{a,b,c\in \mathbb C}\|x+a+b\cos x+c\sin x \|^2$. Using the orthogonality relations I have cut this down to
$$\|x\|^2+2\operatorname{Re}(c) \overbrace{\left\langle x,\sin x \right\rangle}^{2\pi} +|a|^2\|1\|^2 +|b|^2 \|\cos x\|^2+|c|^2\|\sin x\|^2$$

So it seems like $a=b=c=0$ yields the infimum. On the other hand, this seems too simple to be true and I'm afraid I'm missing something.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @πr8 corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noting the oddness/evenness of the functions involved can lead us to:

$$\inf _{a,b,c\in \mathbb C}\int _{[-\pi,\pi]}|x+a+b\cos x+c\sin x | ^2dx=\inf _{c\in \mathbb C}\int _{[-\pi,\pi]}|x+c\sin x | ^2dx$$

Then:

$$\int _{[-\pi,\pi]}|x+c\sin x | ^2dx=\frac{2\pi^3}{3}+4\pi\Re{c}+\pi \vert c\vert ^2=\pi\vert c+2\vert ^2+\left(\frac{2\pi^3}{3}-4\pi\right)$$

which means that we minimise the integral at $a=b=0,c=-2$.

Comment: Where does the integral of the constant go?

Comment: What do you mean? The $a$ from the first integral?

Comment: Yup, in my expansion there was an $|a|^2\| 1\|^2$ term which came from integrating $a^2$

Comment: In fact I do not understand where all the $b$'s from my inner product expansion have vanished aswell

Comment: Right - note that in my first line I say that we can ignore the $a$ and $b\cos x$ terms because they correspond to even functions, and we're approximating a function ($f(x)=x$) which is odd, so we can just keep the $c \sin x$ term.

Comment: I don't understand what that means - this integral is not approximating something, it's just a norm. I think certain inner products with $x$ are zero because of evenness and oddness, but I don't see how you can ignore the terms you say :(

Comment: Apologies, had assumed more context than you might have - this integral is the kind of thing that comes up in $L^2$ approximation / Fourier series, so your question is equivalent to asking which linear combination of $\{ 1, \cos x, \sin x \}$ best approximates $f(x)=x$ in $L^2$ norm.

Comment: If you must persist with the $a, b\cos x$ terms, then it'll just add $|a|^2\| 1\|^2+|b|^2\| \cos x\|^2$ to the expression I landed at - in either case, by that stage it should be obvious that we minimise the integral when $a=b=0$

Comment: Thanks. I want to understand your penultimate comment - why is my question equivalent to which linear combination approximates $x\mapsto x$? I mean, how can I see this equivalence?

Comment: The idea is basically that the function $g$ approximates the function $f$ well if $\int \vert f-g \vert^2 \,dx$ is small. In this case, your answer says that out of all functions of the form $g(x)=a+b\cos x + c\sin x$, the one which is "closest" to $f(x)=x$ is $g(x)=2\sin x$

Comment: Ahh riiight! I completely forgot the norm of the difference is our metric! I should have just imagined parenthesis! Thanks!

Comment: So I could have just calculated the Fourier coefficient of $\sin (x)$ in $x$ and take that as $c$?

Comment: Yep, in effect that's what you've done.

Comment: Yes but much more sloppily - I could have just calculated $\left\langle x,\sin x \right\rangle $ once and be done